# 95% covered how to cover remaining 5 % in test class in Wrapper Class

Tags: unit-test

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class Wrapper_class {
   public list<InnerWrapperclass> Wrapper_list{get;set;}  
    Public class InnerWrapperclass{

    public string Name{get;set;} 
    public string Email{get;set;} 
    public string Phone{get;set;} 

    public string Country{get;set;} 
    public string MgrEmail{get;set;}
    public string State{get;set;} 

    }

 //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type  
    public Wrapper_class(){
         Wrapper_list=new List<InnerWrapperclass>();

        list<Manager__c >Mgrlist=[select Country__c,Email__c,State__c  from Manager__c where createddate!=null order by name ];  
        list<Candidate__c>candList= [SELECT Name,Email__C,Phone__C FROM Candidate__c WHERE createddate!=null  order by name  ];  

    for(Manager__c  mgr:Mgrlist){
    for(Candidate__c Cand:candList){

            InnerWrapperclass iwc = new InnerWrapperclass();
            iwc.Name=Cand.Name;        
            iwc.Email=Cand.Email__C;
            iwc.Phone=Cand.Phone__c;
            iwc.MgrEmail=mgr.Email__C;    
            iwc.Country=mgr.Country__c;
            iwc.State=mgr.State__c ;

** Test Code is not covered here Inside IF Statement**
                if(iwc.Email== iwc.MgrEmail){

                Wrapper_list.add(iwc);

                }

            }
          }
        }
  }
```

**And MY Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class TwoDiffClassDataTestclass{
    static testMethod void TwoDiffClassTestmethod() {

        List<Manager__c> MgrList= new List<Manager__c>();
        List<Candidate__c> candidateList= new List<Candidate__c>();

        Manager__c Mgrobj= new Manager__c(Country__c='a',State__c='123');
        Candidate__c candobj= new Candidate__c( phone__c='123',email__c='a@a.c');
        MgrList.add(Mgrobj);
        candidateList.add(candobj);
        insert MgrList;
        insert candidateList;

        Wrapper_class WC= new Wrapper_class();
        Wrapper_class.InnerWrapperclass IWC= new Wrapper_class.InnerWrapperclass();
        list<Wrapper_class.InnerWrapperclass> IWC_List = new list<Wrapper_class.InnerWrapperclass>();
        IWC_List.add(IWC);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to cover that line. Replace your relevant code in your test case with this:

```
Manager__c Mgrobj= new Manager__c(Country__c='a',State__c='123', email__c='a@a.c');
Candidate__c candobj= new Candidate__c( phone__c='123',email__c='a@a.c');
```

Comment: thanks a lot its achieved 100% but ive a clarification whats is difference between system.assert and system.assertequals. where its used ???

Comment: @kishore , you should use that for every test method. System.assert takes one boolean parameter which asserts the statement to be true. System.assertEquals takes two parameters and assert they are of same value

Comment: so now how should i use those things in my code..

Comment: Add something like: System.assertEquals(WC.Wrapper_list.size(), 1); at the end of your test method.

Answer (score 0):

The line you are specifying is an `if` condition. So just make the test so that it will go inside the `if` statement.

```
Manager__c Mgrobj= new Manager__c(Country__c='a',State__c='123',email__c='a@a.c');
Candidate__c candobj= new Candidate__c( phone__c='123',email__c='a@a.c');
```

With the above code you will be having equal `Email__c` for both candidate and manger which will satisfy your condition.

I hope this is WIP test class, do some assertion to verify your unit test